# Melhor forma para montar uma tabela

Tags: php

Preciso montar uma tabela com alguns documentos. Esses documentos são enviados pelos usuarios da aplicação. Mas dois desses documentos, mesmo que não tenha sido enviado deve aparecer o nome (é constante) na tabela sem a data de nascimento.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Documento</th>
        <th>Data que foi enviado</th>
        <th>Acao</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($documentos as $documento): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $documento->nome; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $documento->data; ?></td>
            <td><input type="file" id="myFile"></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Se o usuario enviou todos os documentos a aplicação retornara algo do tipo:

```
$documentos = array(
new Documentos(1, 'RG', '01/06/2014'),
new Documentos(2, 'CPF', '01/06/2015'),
new Documentos(3, 'OUTROS', '10/10/2013'));
```

Caso contrario deve retornar:

```
$documentos = array(
new Documentos(1, 'RG', '01/06/2014'),
new Documentos(3, 'OUTROS', '10/10/2013'));
```

ou

```
$documentos = array(
new Documentos(3, 'OUTROS', '10/10/2013'));
```

ou

```
$documentos = array();
```

Mesmo que não retorne todos os documentos a apalicação deve exibir o RG: e CPF.

Preciso de ajuda para encontrar a melhor solução.

Comment: Não estou a perceber onde está o seu problema.

Comment: Eu nao entendi nada do que quer fazer. :P

Comment: você já tentou algo como: new Documentos(1, 'RG', null); new Documentos(1, 'CPF', null);

Comment: Sua pergunta está mal elaborada, ninguém entende exatamente o que você quer fazer.